# How to calculate relative path  between 2 directory path?

Tags: python

I have 2 directory:

```
subdir1 = live/events/livepkgr/events/_definst_/
subdir2 = live/streams/livepkgr/streams/_definst_/
```

result must be:

```
diff_subdir = ../../../../streams/livepkgr/streams/_definst_/
```

Comment: What should the function do if the top level directory in each path is different?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html

> os.path.relpath(path[, start]) Return a relative filepath to path
>   either from the current directory or from an optional start point.
>
> start defaults to os.curdir.
>
> Availability: Windows, Unix.
>
> New in version 2.6.

Answer (score 23):

```
>>> subdir1 = "live/events/livepkgr/events/_definst_/"
>>> subdir2 = "live/streams/livepkgr/streams/_definst_/"
>>> import os
>>> os.path.relpath(subdir2, subdir1)
'../../../../streams/livepkgr/streams/_definst_'
>>>
```