# Python: Compute relative path from one directory to another

Tags: python, path, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate relative path  between 2 directory path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178001/how-to-calculate-relative-path-between-2-directory-path)

I need to compute the relative path from one directory to another (i.e. I set a path relative to the working directory, and want to compute the according relative path from any parent/subdir). What is a good way to do that in Python? I could not find much on the subject.

Thanks!

Comment: A search here finds a duplicate question which is answered by pointing to the Python library docs - so what more do you need on this subject?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should take a look at: [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath)

Answer (score 6):

[os.path.relpath()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html) does this for you and is available in Python 2.6 and above.

Comment: *That feeling when...* you answer a second later than the [top-upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8607302/2809027).

Answer (score -2):

You can set the relative path using os.path.dirname(**file**)

os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), "filename")

Comment: This is not what os.path.dirname does. It returns the directory of a path object.