# How to calculate relative path between two directorys in different mounts in Windows?

Tags: python, windows, path

I refer this [How to calculate relative path  between 2 directory path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178001/how-to-calculate-relative-path-between-2-directory-path)

It works well if two directories are in same mount (ex: C:\ or :D)

But if two directories are in different mounts, I have error like this:

`ValueError: path is on mount C:, start on mount D:`

I think the reason is because Windows does not actually have `root` directory like Linux.

So, is it possible to  calculate relative path between two directorys in different mounts in Windows ?

Comment: No, it's not possible, or even meaningful, if you're using DOS drive-letter mount points. Each drive has a separate root. It's possible if you mount volume D: in a directory of volume C: using mountvol.exe.

Comment: Also, it's sort of possible if you're using the NT API, which does have a global root directory in the object manager namespace. But handling relative paths (see [`OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES.RootDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557749)) isn't as general as POSIX because they have to be sibling or child objects. NT doesn't implement ".." to reference the parent object. Plus `os.path.relpath` doesn't work right with NT paths anyway.